# What are the Borels/parabolics of the orthogonal or symplectic groups?

Tags: reference-request, algebraic-groups

Does anyone know where I can find info about the Borel subgroups and parabolic subgroups of algebraic groups?  I know what they are for the general linear group and for the special linear group you can just take the determinant 1 elements of a Borel for the general linear group.  But I'm assuming that this doesn't always work because when I tried it for the orthogonal group I got that it was just diagonal matrices that square to the identity.

Ideally I'm looking for a reference which gives explicit computations of Borels, the root system, and parabolics.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

If you choose your bilinear forms nicely (so that the standard maximal flag includes a maximal totally isotropic subspace and a subspace minimal with respect to the quotient being totally isotropic), then you can indeed just do the intersection.

You can see that something like this has to work because a Borel subgroup of $H$ is contained in a Borel subgroup of $G$ whenever $H$ is a closed subgroup of $G$. The trick is *which* Borel subgroup!

At any rate this is handled nicely in Malle–Testerman (2011) on [page 38](http://books.google.com/books?id=4l52zICEq3EC&pg=PA38).

- Malle, Gunter; Testerman, Donna.
  *Linear algebraic groups and finite groups of Lie type.*
  Cambridge Studies in Advanced Mathematics, 133.
  Cambridge University Press, Cambridge, 2011.
  xiv+309 pp. ISBN: 978-1-107-00854-0
  MR[2850737](http://www.ams.org/mathscinet-getitem?mr=2850737)